# Можно ли написать "абстрактный" enum?

Tags: java

Есть такой enum:

```
public enum AlbumPrivacy {

    public_(0),
    friendsOnly(1),
    familyOnly(2),
    friendsAndFamily(3),
    private_(4);

    private final int _value;
    private static AlbumPrivacy[] _values;

    private AlbumPrivacy(int value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return _value;
    }

    public static AlbumPrivacy fromInt(int i) {
        if (_values == null)
            _values = AlbumPrivacy.values();

        for (AlbumPrivacy b : _values) {
            if (b.getValue() == i) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Зачем такое нагородил? Удобно, когда пишешь в базу - быстро сохранять в int и назад.

Но очень не удобно для каждого нового enum писать копию кода. А извернуться и убрать эту дубликацию кода нельзя?

И второй вопрос - правильно ли я сделал, что храню список values, а не каждый раз дёргаю при вызове `fromInt`?

**UPD:**

Может тогда вот так сделать:

```
public class EnumUtils {

    private static Map<Class<?>, Object[]> _enums;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends Enum<T>> T fromInt(Class<T> clazz, int index) {
        if (_enums == null)
            _enums = U2.map();

        Object[] values = _enums.get(clazz);

        if (values == null)
        {
            Enum<T>[] _values = clazz.getEnumConstants();
            values = new Object[_values.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < _values.length; i++)
                values[i] = _values[i];

            _enums.put(clazz, values);
        }

        return (T) values[index];
    }
}
```

А enum объявлять по простому, без всяких номеров.

**UPD2:**

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T fromInt(Class<T> clazz, int index) {
        return clazz.getEnumConstants()[index];
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У каждого `enum` и так есть порядковое значение поля — метод `ordinal()`. Если у вас все `value` идут по порядку, посто делайте

```
public enum AlbumPrivacy {
    public_, // 0
    friendsOnly, // 1
    familyOnly, // 2
    friendsAndFamily, // 3
    private_;  // 4
}
```

Для определения номера по enum:

```
int n = AlbumPrivacy.friendsOnly.ordinal();
```

Для определения enum по номеру:

```
AlbumPrivacy value = AlbumPrivacy.values()[3];
```

Если вас это не устраивает (скажем, номера могут идти с дырками), можно во-первых, реализовать интерфейс, а во-вторых сделать метод `fromInt` универсальным.

```
interface Ordinal {
    int getValue();
}

public enum AlbumPrivacy implements Ordinal {

    public_(0),
    friendsOnly(1),
    familyOnly(2),
    friendsAndFamily(3),
    private_(4);

    private final int _value;

    private AlbumPrivacy(int value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    @Override    
    public int getValue() {
        return _value;
    }
}

// Где-нибудь в утилитном классе:
public static <T extends Enum<T> & Ordinal> T fromInt(Class<T> clazz, int i) {
    T[] values = clazz.getEnumConstants();
    for(T value : values) {
        if(value.getValue() == i) return value;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: да я это знал. Просто наткнулся на тему http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157755/how-to-convert-enum-value-to-int Плюсов много и в вопросе и в ответе, спрашивается чего тогда они стали городить...

Comment: а, сейчас посмотрю вторую часть вашего поста.

Comment: странно, не могу добавить в начале собаку-ваш ник...

Comment: А как тебе такое решение? (см. первый пост после UPD)

Comment: @YShinkarev, ну если вам принципиальна экономия на копировании массива enum-значений. Что-то мне подсказывает, что она непринципиальна.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на вторую часть вопроса. Нет, вы неправильно делаете, что запоминаете `values`. Метод `getEnumConstants` уже запоминает результат, нет никакой необходимости запоминать его еще раз.

Comment: Да, сейчас посмотрел в исходниках - смысла нет. Тогда вообще в одну строчку.